# What is the recurrence relation of generating triangle?

Tags: recurrence-relations, triangles, generating-functions

I wanna make recurrence relation of making triangle.

For all the sides $a,b,c$

$a+b+c=n$

So the series should be $\{0,0,1,0,1,1,2,1,3\dots\}$

It's really messing up my heads

If you know what I'm trying to say, please help me find recurrence relation

Comment: Are you sure the $9^{th}$ entry is $2$ instead of $3$?

Comment: sorry i did only see the case (3,3,3)(2,3,4) i didn't know there is (1,4,4) too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up to my understanding, you are asking for

> the number of triangles with integer sides for given perimeter $n$.

There are some ambiguities what number of triangles means. The number you gave is consistent with the assumption that two triangles of sides $( a_1, b_1, c_1 )$ and $(a_2, b_2, c_2)$ are considered to be the same when and only when $(a_2,b_2,c_2)$ is an permutation of $(a_1,b_1,c_1)$.

We will adopt this assumption for counting.

Let $a, b, c$ be the sides of any triangle. 
Let $N_n$ be the number of triangles for perimeter $a + b + c = n$.
The number you ask equals to the size of the set
$$N_n = \# \left\{ (a,b,c) \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}^3 : 1 \le a \le b \le c; 
\begin{align}
a + b &> c\\
b + c &> a \\
c + a &> b
\end{align}
\right\}$$
When we assume $1 \le a \le b \le c$, two of the triangle equalities $b + c > a$, $c + a > b$ satisfied automatically. Let $p = b - a$ and $q = c - b$, the remaining triangle equality reduces to $q < a$.

Extend the definition of $N_n$ to negative $n$ by setting $N_n = 0$ whenever $n \le 0$.
The OGF for the $N_n$ equals to

$$\begin{align}
f(x) 
&\stackrel{def}{=} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty N_n x^n
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty N_n x^n 
= \sum_{\substack{1 \le a \le b \le c\\a+ b > c}} x^{a+b+c}\\
&= \sum_{a=1}^\infty x^a \sum_{p=0}^\infty x^{a+p} \sum_{q=0}^{a-1} x^{a+p+q}
= \sum_{a=1}^\infty x^{3a}\sum_{p=0}^\infty x^{2p}\sum_{q=0}^{a-1} x^q
= \sum_{a=1}^\infty x^{3a}\sum_{p=0}^\infty x^{2p}\left(\frac{1-x^a}{1-x}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{1-x}\left(\sum_{a=1}^\infty(x^{3a} - x^{4a})\right)\left(\sum_{p=0}^\infty x^{2p}\right)
= \frac{1}{1-x}\left(\frac{x^3}{1-x^3}-\frac{x^4}{1-x^4}\right)\left(\frac{1}{1-x^2}\right)\\
&= \frac{x^3}{(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^4)}
\end{align}
$$

If you really want a recurrence relation for $N_n$, you can multiply both sides
of above expression by 
$$(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^4) = 1-x^2-x^3-x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7-x^9$$
Compare coefficients on both sides, one obtain

$$N_{n} - N_{n-2} - N_{n-3} - N_{n-4} + N_{n-5} + N_{n-6} + N_{n-7} - N_{n-9} = 
\begin{cases}
1, & n = 3\\
0, & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$
Together with the initial conditions $N_n = 0$ for $n \le 0$, this is enough
to determine the values of $N_n$ for all $n > 0$.

This sequence $N_n$ is known as 
[Alcuin's sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcuin's_sequence),
you can find a table of its values for small $n$ on [OEIS A005044](http://oeis.org/A005044). Look at references in both the wiki and OEIS for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This is exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Plugging your sequence into OEIS gives [A005044](http://oeis.org/A005044)  Among the formulas is the explicit $a(n) = (6*n^2 + 18*n - 9*(-1)^n*(2*n + 3) - 36*\sin(\pi*n/2) - 36*\cos(\pi*n/2) + 64*\cos(2*\pi*n/3) - 1)/288$